# how to use pandas to transfer the data in csv file, line to the row

Tags: csv, pandas

My original data is like this :

```
time    2016/9/30   2016/6/30   2016/3/31   2015/12/31

value   1.09    0.72    0.43    1.56

stock   10.38   10  11.71   11.
```

and want to change it :

```
time    value   stock

2016/9/30   1.09    10.38

2016/6/30   0.72    10

2016/3/31   0.43    11.71

2015/12/31  1.56    11.29
```

It seems very simple ,but i tried many way, but all failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the data as it is and use [Transpose](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) & practice [10 Minutes to pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer。sorry i did not describe my question very clearly。                                                                                                   my final result hopes the 'time' as the index, i did try use "df.T" as in your answer, but the "0  1 " is not want i want(and i don't know how to delete them), and after using "df.T" , i can't set time as the index.

Comment: Indeed you have to hold the resultant df.T to a variable and check the index. Indeed time becomes the index. Unless you practice/follow 10 minutes pandas it is going to be very challenging.

Comment: you are right，now the time becomes the index, but the index is ['time',2016-09-30,2016-6-30,2016-3-31,2015-12-31]. while i hope the index is [2016-09-30,2016-6-30,2016-3-31,2015-12-31]

Comment: thanks very much, it works. i just started learning python, and should practice more. thanks again, it helps a lot.